# Null Pointer Exception when accessing a method of a class extends view from inside a sensor listener

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-sensors, surfaceholder

I want to pass the readings of a sensor to the class `MyCompassView` that extends a view, and based on the readings from the sensor to be passed, a pointer is changing its orientation. Actually, all this works fine, i tested it. But the same concept when I tried to implement it on a surface view that opens the camera preview on the surface, it does not work and crashes the app.
Simply, I have `SurfaceViewHolder` class the holds the camera preview, the `MyCompassView` class as described above and the `MainActivity` that should has both views of `MyCompassView` and `SurfaceHolder` on its surface. The way I used to overlay the `MainActivity` with these views is as posted below: please help me to find why the method `myCompassView.update(azimuth);`that is located inside the `onSensorChanged` cause the logcate to say"Null Pointer Exception"

***UPDATE***:

When I omit `myCompassView.update(azimuth);` the app works but with drawings in the         `MyCompassView` class is static not indicting orientation, ofcourse because of the
`myCompassView.update(azimuth);` is not activated.However, when i activate that method
the app crashs and the logcat generates the posted output.
Line 100 is  `myCompassView.update(azimuth);`

MainActivity.java

```
     public class Mainactivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements SensorEventListener {

    private SurfaceHolderActivity myCameraSurfaceHolder;
    private View compassOverLayView;
    private MyCompassView myCompassView;
    private LayoutInflater loiViewInflater = null;
            ..
            ..
            //myCompassView = new MyCompassView(getApplicationContext());               
            myCompassView = (MyCompassView) findViewById(R.id.mycompass);
        myCameraSurfaceHolder = new SurfaceHolderActivity(this);
        setContentView(myCameraSurfaceHolder);          
                    
        loiViewInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        loiViewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        compassOverLayView = loiViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_viewactivity, null);
        addContentView(compassOverLayView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ...
    ...
            @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            valuesAccelerometer = event.values.clone();
            /*for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                valuesAccelerometer[i] = event.values[i];
            }*/
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            valuesMagneticField = event.values.clone();
            /*for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
            }*/
            break;
        }
        
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(MatrixR, MatrixI, 
                valuesMagneticField, valuesAccelerometer);
        if (success) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(MatrixR, MatrixValues);
            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(MatrixValues[0]);
            pitch = Math.toDegrees(MatrixValues[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(MatrixValues[2]);             
            myCompassView.update(azimuth);
        } 
    }
```

Activity_ViewActivity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.augrealtest00.Mainactivity" >

<view 
        android:id="@+id/mycompass" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        class="com.example.augrealtest01.MyCompassView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at 
com.example.augrealtest01.Mainactivity.onSensorChanged(Mainactivity.java:100)
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at         android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManag    er.java:467)
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at  
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at    
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at    
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-26 23:38:15.136: E/AndroidRuntime(18873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
```

Comment: what is at line 100 of Mainactivity.java ?

Comment: it is the myCompassView.update(azimuth);  please see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that line :

```
myCompassView = (MyCompassView) findViewById(R.id.mycompass);
```

to be called *after* :

```
setContentView(myCameraSurfaceHolder);
....
addContentView(compassOverLayView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

So the view with id = `mycompass` is attached to activity's view hierarchy.

Otherwise, `findViewById` will return null, thus your NPE.

Comment: Thank you. In concept, you are correct, but for our knowledge,the line you suggested to be moved should not be placed after "setContentView(myCameraSurfaceHolder);" BUT should be placed after "addContentView(compassOverLayView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));"

Comment: I tried it and it worked now.  but i dont know why it goes like this, any ideas?

Comment: it is obvious. You can only try to find view by Id when the view with this id is attached to your activity. It always happens _after_ you set your activity view with `setContentView`. (may be in your case even in `addContentView`). If you do it before, you will have `null` as you did.